# Formula working in cell but not in conditional formatting

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have the following formula which works as desired when entered into a cell. However, the same formula does not work when I try to use it in conditional formatting:

`=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(U2,DEALS!$A$2:F,5,FALSE), "Likes"), O2>=VLOOKUP(U2,DEALS!$A$2:F,4,FALSE), Q2>=VLOOKUP(U2,DEALS!$A$2:F,4,FALSE))`

[image: Formula in cell]

[image: Formula in conditional formatting]

I haven't had any issues with conditional formatting up until now with this formula, and I am really not sure what is the issue as this is not my expertise.

Appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(U2, INDIRECT("DEALS!A2:F"), 5, 0), "Likes"), 
 O2>=VLOOKUP(U2, INDIRECT("DEALS!A2:F"), 4, 0), 
 Q2>=VLOOKUP(U2, INDIRECT("DEALS!A2:F"), 4, 0))
```

conditional formatting does not understand references coming from different sheets if not indirected

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks once again! I'll read more about the indirect function to better understand it all.